# How could I display text only on a particular subdomain URL in Rails4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a multi-tenant Rails 4 app. I would like to display some instructions for testers before they log in on their 'test' subdomain account. 
So text should be only displayed for that particular URL, but not for other subdomains. How could I do this?

E.g. the following is incorrect, but an example of what I would like to achieve:

```
#in devise/sessions/new.html.erb 

<% if url == 'http://test.lvh.me:3000/users/sign_in' %>
  <p>Some text displayed here, just for this subdomain...</p>
  <h2>Sign in</h2>
  ...
<% else %>
  <h2>Sign in</h2>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`request.subdomain`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-subdomain)

```
<% if request.subdomain == 'test' %>
  <p>Some text displayed here, just for this subdomain...</p>
  <h2>Sign in</h2>
  ...
<% else %>
  <h2>Sign in</h2>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a different layout for that subdomain.

In your `ApplicationController`:

```
  layout :set_layout

  private

  def set_layout
    request.subdomain == 'test' ? 'test' : 'public'
  end
```

And in the layout you can add more text before the `<%= yield %>`

You can read more about layouts here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html